# Making a DataGridView Horizontal Scroll Event Scroll Another Control

Tags: vb.net

I have a DataGridView with a panel above it, that contains a group of textboxes above each column.  My DataGridView has a horizontal scroll bar.  What I want to do is when the DataGridView scrolls horizontally, scroll the panel with textboxes above it, so they stay aligned.

I tried handling the DataGridView's scroll event, but I'm not sure what to do with it.  Does anyone have any examples with this?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry - I thought this was an ASP.NET quesiton = ignore my answer.

Comment: @user842818 yea sorry about that :(